# I want to collect the data frame column values in an array list to conduct some computations, is it possible?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-phoenix

I am loading data from phoenix through this:

```
val tableDF = sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame("Hbtable", Array("ID", "distance"), conf = configuration)
```

and want to carry out the following computation on the column values `distance`:

```
val list=Array(10,20,30,40,10,20,0,10,20,30,40,50,60)//list of values from the column distance
val first=list(0)
val last=list(list.length-1)
var m = 0; 
for (a <- 0 to list.length-2) {
  if (list(a + 1) < list(a) && list(a+1)>=0)
  {
     m = m + list(a)
  } 
}
val totalDist=(m+last-first)
```

Comment: Do you want to do the computations on the `DataFrame` or do you want to collect the column values into an actual `Array` type?

Comment: Any thing is fine, at the end i want to find the total distance as given in the code. i prefer to carry out the computations on an array as it is easy, you can suggest me even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. It returns `Array[Any]`

```
`val array = df.select("distance").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

If you want to get the data type properly, then you can use. It returns the `Array[Int]`

```
val array = df.select("distance").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Int]).collect()
```

Comment: Shankar, can we do this with out using collect because collect brings all the data to driver right? so it will be a problem the data is very huge

Comment: How to achieve the same in java?